# iTunes install tracking

Tags: ios, itunes, tracking

I should be able to track the click to install conversion, with tools like Flurry or Adjust (ie. user clicks on a generated link, and is redirected to my app on the iOS AppStore and I could see, the click and the install).

How does this work, from the technical side. I'am generating a link, where I can obviously track the click very easily, but how do I get the conversion, from click to install? I can redirect the user to the AppStore page, but I would need to provide a ID (or similar) which the AppStore will provide my app, that the respective SDK can track the actual install.

Could you provide me some insight, how this works? Through iTunes Affiliate?

Answer (score 0):

Through Flurry it's really easy if you own the apps:

1. Flurry SDK must be installed on both the apps (let call them A and B).
2. On Flurry website goto Company Tab -> "Conversions" -> "Up-Selling" -> "Create New Up-Sell..."
3. Then add the conversion you are trying to measure for example from A to B (you can also measure B to A separately).

This would make Flurry start measuring this.

For now you cannot measure exactly how many is by your ad at app A or if the user got both apps separately it would still get into that count. The way to measure that is not so complex it's involves Flurry creating a unique ID for the device (they are probably using Advertising ID - IDFA or other unique identifier you can get from the iOS SDK) and if this ID appears on the other app it would count as up sell (if A is before B).

Doing all that on your own without Flurry is too much because you would need servers just for that task. If you are willing to do so just on server side save each user_id (IDFA or other similar) the APP_ID that connected to it (it is pretty easy to get the bundle_id so you could use it or get from the iTunes API the exact APP_ID), then you would have for each device which apps he has that you installed your SDK on. from there you could estimate your conversion rate. On top of that you could register each link press on your server and then have another estimation of clicks from the SDK itself or sending the user to your server with his IDFA (or similar) and APP_ID. To make statistic more valuable you can measure time from the click till the actual running of the advertised app etc.

For now Apple doesn't provide this service themselves. not through iTunes connect or through other systems I know.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Doesn't even scrath the surface to answer my question.

Comment: I've extend the answer. Can you further explain your question? What exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: I would like to know how Flurry / Adjust etc is achieving the tracking technically. I'am able to generate a link, which leads to the App Store page of my app. Through these link the services track click (which is obviously easy), but how do they track if the user installs the app or simply closes the store again.

Comment: I think I've explained that through my latest edits. They are using a unique identifier given by the iOS SDK. On the early days it way called UDID now it changed to advertising identifier (IDFA). You can check into this, I think now they have 2 identifiers one for the user and one for the device itself which have restrictions when using. The SDK knows what app is running it so it is just sending this info to server as I explained. What else missing?

Comment: And now? What is exactly missing?